# Error when using pip install: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package-name>"

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm trying to install `django-trumbowyg` https://github.com/sandino/django-trumbowyg to my app

When I did `pip install django-trumbowyg`, it returned this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-trumbowyg (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-trumbowyg
```

Does anyone know what this means? And how I can fix it?

Comment: The package is for Python2 only, are you on Python3?

Comment: Yeah I'm on python3. I've updated the link in my edit, not sure if it's the same package but i've gone through some of the code (like urls.py) and it seems to be python3.

Comment: You can try to install it manually by bypassing PyPI by doing :`pip install git+https://github.com/sandino/django-trumbowyg`.

Answer (score 1):

As https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-trumbowyg#downloads shows, there's only a binary package for Python2 at PyPI.

So, you have to install the package directly from the official sources [as pointed out by Rishav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218164/error-when-using-pip-install-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requi#comment73507995_43218164) in the meantime.

Then ask the developer to upload a source package to PyPI and/or build the wheel as [universal](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#defining-the-python-version).

Answer (score 0):

You may also get this error if your company firewall doesnt allow any package from external source. you might need to add a proxy in that case.

for example: pip install django-trumbowyg --proxy=proxy.companydomain.com: